# How to fix Books.app in Catalina

Tags: books, catalina

I recently updated to Catalina, and am now unable to open books (ePubs/PDFs alike) via Books. These books are there, I can drag them out to my Desktop or sync them to my iPad, but they do not open in Books.

Instead, an alert is displayed with the following text:

The operation couldn’t be completed. (BKAgentServiceErrorDomain error 8.)
A black-HUD-ed spinner appears on the book's icon, spinning indefinitely.

How do I resolve this issue?